# Get list of SSID's in range & connect to a particular SSID : iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I need to scan list of SSID's in range and connect to a particular SSID of my choice.
Airport Utility app on store has WiFi Scan feature. I am looking for same API to scan all near by SSID's.

Basically, I have some list of SSID & its password in database.
When I am in proximity of  any SSID which exist in my Database, I need to connect to that SSID, when my app is running.

Is there any way for doing this?
Also, whether it is possible or not?

Thanks.